# What is missing from this minimal UITextFieldDelegate implementation, to cause crashing?

Tags: swift, uitextfielddelegate

The crash occurs upon selecting the Text Field in the simulator. The debugger seems to tell me nothing useful.

```
import UIKit
class TextField: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {}
```

In the View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = TextField()
}
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! // assigned in IB.
```

Comment: can you give your crash log in Xcode?

Comment: I think the problem is the delegate (a TextField) has been removed from memory before you select the text field. You have to create a variable of your viewcontroller : var textFieldDelegate = TextField() to keep reference to that object

Comment: I've thought of that also, and am testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextField.delegate is **unowned**, so the delegates were being deallocated after viewDidLoad returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the delegate to `TextField()`

Just set the delegate to self, because you use the UITextFieldDelegate in your class:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Comment: If you did that, you'd be putting text field code in a controller for a view. The code belongs in a controller for a Text Field.

Comment: No. @Christian is correct. You create an instance of `TextField` and assign that to the delegate. This is plain nonsense.

Comment: Last time I checked, separation of concerns was considered the opposite of programming nonsense. The best way I can think of, to separate concerns, given what Apple has supplied, is to create an object that implements UITextFieldDelegate, for each UITextField.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the delegate to a property instead

first add *customTextFieldDelegate* as a property

```
var customTextFieldDelegate = TextField()
```

and in ViewDidload

```
self.textField.delegate = self.customTextFieldDelegate
```

Comment: The self. doesn't do anything, but yes, that's essentially what has to be done. It seems strange to me that a reference to a delegate wouldn't be strong. What else would be more likely to want a reference to a delegate that the thing that's delegating responsibility?

Comment: short answer is to prevent *strong reference cycle* .. 
UItableView datasource is another place ...  you can find more about it in the swift guide from apple under 'ARC'  there is a note saying 
"*If you try to access an unowned reference after the instance that it references is deallocated, you will trigger a runtime error*"